# How to resolve error "object reference not set to an instance of an object" in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I installed SQL Server 2014 Management Studio on my system few months age. It was working fine until yesterday. But today, when I started SSMS and clicked on "New Query" option, I got an error

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

Please provide a solution to resolve this error.

Comment: What has changed on your computer since yesterday?

Comment: And have you ever applied a service pack? What is the version of SSMS in Help > About?

Comment: What is the version of SSMS? Usually these errors occur when there's something that was corrupted. What has changed on your computer since yesterday? Try to execute again the setup of SQL Server and choose the "Repair" option to repair your components.

Comment: Try below options to see if it resolves the error (A) Repair the .net framework (B) Repair the SQL Server. Go to Add/remove programs Microsoft SQL Server 2014(x64) -> Uninstall/Change -> Repair. Select the instance that you want to repair here.