# SSMS for 2008r2 job activity monitor works...SSMS for 2016 rc1 error message

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

Wanting to use the latest and greatest, I downloaded the SSMS 2016 rc1 (and have downloaded the previous previews, liking what I see) and I have a situation that is similar to [How to resolve error "object reference not set to an instance of an object" in SQL Server 2014](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120942/how-to-resolve-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-in-s)
. Things work on the RC1 up until I get to the Jobs Activity monitor. Opening the monitor gives me the error message of `Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (mscorlib)`. Am I getting the error due to my db being 2008r2 and the SSMS is looking for a component in the wrong place? It actually seems to be the only area that doesn't work as advertised.

Full text of error follows:

> ===================================
>
> Cannot show requested dialog.
>
> ===================================
>
> Unable to execute requested command.
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.ToolMenuItemHelper.OnCreateAndShowForm(IServiceProvider
>   sp, XmlDocument doc)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.RunningFormsTable.RunningFormsTableImpl.ThreadStarter.StartThread()
>
> ===================================
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (mscorlib)
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName,
>   String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder,
>   Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection)    at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString)    at ..(Object , ResolveEventArgs )    at
>   System.AppDomain.OnResourceResolveEvent(RuntimeAssembly assembly,
>   String resourceName)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetResource(RuntimeAssembly
>   assembly, String resourceName, UInt64& length, StackCrawlMarkHandle
>   stackMark, Boolean skipSecurityCheck)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(String
>   name, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean skipSecurityCheck)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(String
>   name)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.ResourceHelper.GetBitmapResource(String
>   strQualifiedName)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.ResourceHelper.InitializeLockModeBitmaps()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.ResourceHelper.EnsureBitmapsInitialized()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ActivityMonitor.ActivityMonitorUserControl.InitializeActivityMonitor(IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider, IActivityMonitor plugin)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ActivityMonitor.ActivityMonitorUserControl..ctor(IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider, IActivityMonitor plugin)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.ActivityMonitorForm.InitializeInnerUserControl(IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider, XmlDocument xmlDoc, String pluginType, Object
>   extendedContext)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.ActivityMonitorForm.InternalInitialization(IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider, XmlDocument xmlDoc, Object extendedContext)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.ActivityMonitorForm..ctor(XmlDocument
>   xmlDoc, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)

Comment: What patch level is your 2008 R2 Server?

Comment: 10.50.6220.0 (X64)

Comment: It works for me when connecting to same patch level you have.

Comment: Will also say that I opened  the original SSMS from the SQL Server 2008 r2 folder and can open the Job Activity Monitor with no issues. Looked through all connection properties to no avail.

Comment: What SSMS version are you using? Latest is 13.0.13000.55.

Comment: RC2 is out now, did problem go away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that it was indeed a bug that was squashed with the release of RC2 on 4/4/16. It had been occurring since the October preview, and I appreciate everyone's time and attention.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is not a fully released version yet, I'd recommend opening a [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback) for this issue to make sure it gets addressed (I couldn't find a similar one myself after a bit of searching).

I'm not sure that it's within the scope of DBA.se to troubleshoot release candidate software issues. I'd probably stick with SSMS 2014 until 2016 is fully released.

Actually, I'd stick with the appropriate version for my server since I find it annoying to have a GUI trying to do tricks my old dog doesn't know.